# Setup static IP in redhat 6

Tags: rhel, dhcp, configuration

I installed Redhat 6 x86_64. I am using the Network connection screen to set a static IP address like below (I want two PC's in my house to see each other: one Redhat PC and one Mac)

```
192.168.0.5  
255.255.255.0  
192.168.0.1
```

When I run `ifconfig` it displays only `lo` and `virbr0` information. I don't know what these items are (I don't really know much about network settings).

When I try `ifconfig -a` it displays `eth0`, `lo`, `sit0` and `virbr0`. The information for  `eth0` is as follows:

```
Link encap : Ethernet HWaddr 90:2B:34:74:05:30
BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets:192 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
RX bytes 53811 (52.5 KiB) TX bytes:468 (468.0 b)
Interrupt:29 Base address:0xc000
```

Could someone help me to point out if anything wrong with my setting or how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can provide static IP by editing the file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` as `root` user in Redhat.

It should look like this:

```
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=STATIC
IPADDR=192.168.0.5
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=192.168.0.1
ONBOOT=yes
```

After saving this file. You need to restart the network daemon using following command.

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/network stop
$ sudo /etc/init.d/network start
```

This should provide IP address to `eth0` interface also. And `ifconfig` command should list `eth0` also.

Comment: thanks for your quick answer. i did the same thing before but cannot solve. i ran ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.5 netmask 255.255.255.0. and it solved my problem. i don't know what's wrong. With this setting, when i restarted by using /etc/init.d/network stop/start, then ifconfig --> again it hide the [eth0]

Comment: Can you try booting the computer once. After that `ifconfig` command should show everytime `eth0`. You can try using `sudo ifup eth0` if you don't want to reboot.

Comment: restart help solving my problem. thank you very much

Comment: You probably want to make sure that the `network` service starts on boot, so you'll want to run `/sbin/chkconfig network on` as root.

Comment: According to RHEL 6 documentation, there is no such value as BOOTPROTO=STATIC. https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-networkscripts-interfaces.html

Answer (score 1):

After you configure the ip address run the following commands

```
service NetworkManager stop
chkconfig NetworkManager off
```

It will retain the provided ip even after booting.